# Touchpad issue with my hp mini

Tags: synaptics

I am new to ubuntu. Installed later version but having issues with my touchpad.
I've got an Hp mini can someone guide me step by step how to solve it.
Even where write the code single step by step.
Any help it is really appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about the issues you are having. What exactly is the problem you are experiencing with your touchpad?

Comment: the right click does not work. so I was wondering if there is anything I can do like found driver package or something similar to make the touchpad work. it treats the right click as left click, it works only if i do two very quick click on the bottom right corner of the touchpad. there is any way to fix this?

Comment: I am new to ubuntu trying still to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution for your problem, take a look at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966016&page=2) on the Ubuntu forums.

Post #18: Kernel Patch (for use with kernel 3.2.0-24-generic-pae)

Post #107: Kernel Patch (for use with kernel 3.2.0-29-generic-pae)

If you are not currently running either kernel version 3.2.0-24 or 3.2.0-29, you can try modifying the patch for your kernel (you will see in the forum thread that others have been successful doing this). This is simpler than it sounds:

1. Download and extract the .tar archive that user AnotherMuggle has provided in post #18
2. Locate 'dkms.conf', and open it for editing
3. In 'dkms.conf', replace all instances of '3.2.0-24' with whatever kernel version you are currently running (3.2.0-27, 3.2.0-30, etc.)
4. Follow AnotherMuggle's directions from post #18, replacing all instances of '3.2.0-24' with the version number you used in the newly-edited 'dkms.conf'

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: Now the touchpad scroll stop working. It works perfectly with the usb mouse, but with the touchpad no luck. It also disappear the touchpad section in All setting menu. Trying to find something but not luck for now....

Comment: I did reboot it started to work again...... weird